# How determinate the torsion subgroup and the normal maximal $\pi$-subgroup of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ the real numbers and the integers, respectively. Consider $G =\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. Find

$O_{\pi}(G)$ - ie, the (unique) normal maximal $\pi$-subgroup of $G$;
$T(G)$ - ie, the torsion subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $G$ is a torsion abelian group it satisfies the $p$-group decomposition $G\cong\bigoplus G_p$, where each $G_p$ is the subgroup of all $p$-torsion elements (i.e. elts whose order is a power of $p$) of $G$, equivalently the union $\bigcup G[p^r]$ where $G[n]$ is defined as the subgroup of all $g\in G$ satisfying $g^n=e$.

If $G$ is a torsion abelian group and $\pi\subseteq{\cal P}$ a set of primes, a $\pi$-subgroup of $G$ is one in which every element has order which factors into primes only coming from $\pi$. Thus the maximal $\pi$-subgroup of any torsion abelian group $G$ is $\bigoplus_{p\in\pi}G_p$. Abelian automatically implies normal.

Note that $\bf R$ is an uncountable $\frak c$-dimensional $\bf Q$-vector space, so ${\bf R}\cong \bigoplus_{\frak c}{\bf Q}$. As $\bf Z$ is a subgroup of only one of the factors of $\bf Q$ in this decomposition, quotienting by $\bf Z$ only affects that factor, that is we have ${\bf R}/{\bf Z}\cong {\bf Q}/{\bf Z}\times\bigoplus_{\frak c}{\bf Q}$. All of the latter factors are nontorsion, so $T({\bf R/Z})\cong{\bf Q}/{\bf Z}$.

Finally, we have the Prüfer decomposition ${\bf Q}/{\bf Z}\cong \bigoplus_p {\bf Z}(p^\infty)$. The Prüfer $p$-groups are defined additively as ${\bf Z}[p^{-1}]/{\bf Z}$, or multiplicatively as the roots of unity in $\bf C$ with $p$-power order. This is in fact the $p$-torsion decopmosition of $G={\bf Q}/{\bf Z}$, so the maximal $\pi$-subgroup is $\bigoplus_{p\in\pi}{\bf Z}(p^\infty)$.

*Tangent*. An equivalent formulation is ${\bf Z}(p^\infty)\cong{\bf Q}_p/{\bf Z}_p$, where ${\bf Q}_p$ is the field of $p$-adic numbers with subring ${\bf Z}_p$ the $p$-adic integers. This allows the Prüfer decomposition to generalize to arbitrary global fields (quotienting a global field by its ring of integers decomposes as a direct sum of the local fields modulo their valuation subrings), in particular the function field case recovers the idea of partial fraction decomposition in algebraic language.

Comment: @Peter Tamaroff, Where can I find references on this decomposition Prufer you quoted?

Comment: You mean to ask that to sea turtles. I didn't post this answer.

Comment: @AgenorAndrade There is a Wikipedia article on the [Prufer $p$-groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group) if you're interested. KCd writes on the [character group of $\bf Q$](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/characterQ.pdf) if you're interested in deeper number theory application. Ultimately, the fact of the decomposition is a basic exercise in abelian group theory: the $p$-component of ${\bf Q}/{\bf Z}$ will be rationals for which $p^rx\in{\bf Z}$ for some $r\ge0$ i.e. rationals with $p$-power denominators (modulo $\bf Z$), i.e. ${\bf Z}[p^{-1}]/{\bf Z}$.